# How to build docker images using a Declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to using Jenkins....

I'm trying to automate the production of an image (to be stashed in  a repo) using a declarative Jenkinsfile. I find the documentation to be confusing (at best). Simply put, how can I convert the following scripted example (from [the docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers))

```
node {
    checkout scm
    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
    customImage.push()
}
```

to a declarative Jenkinsfile....

Comment: The question is, of course, a specific example of the more generic question - How do I use the Docker Pipeline features in general from a declarative Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Important to note that (at the time of writing this comment) the [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) is `up for adoption` and looking for new maintainers. [Last release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/releases/tag/563.vd5d2e5c4007f) was 5 months ago (Dec, 2022).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can [use scripted pipeline blocks in a declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) as a workaround

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                echo 'Starting to build docker image'

                script {
                    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                    customImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hunted everywhere I could think of (including the link you referenced). The docs state

    "For most use-cases, the script step should be unnecessary in Declarative Pipelines, but it can provide a useful "escape hatch." 

so I kept looking. It does seem odd - to me at least - that the preferred way (declarative) omits such functionality.

Comment: With this approach I only get "docker: not found".

Comment: You need docker cli to be installed for sure

Comment: Please explain the benefit of wrapping old scripting syntax in the new declarative syntax.

Comment: as the OP asked how to call docker from his declarative pipeline, and he already has scripted pipeline example.

Comment: @jokarl the "docker" object ends up executing commands that invoke the docker binary on the underlying platform.  This error indicate that there is no docker binary in the PATH.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using following approach:

```
steps {
   withDockerRegistry([ credentialsId: "<CREDENTIALS_ID>", url: "<PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL>" ]) {
      // following commands will be executed within logged docker registry
      sh 'docker push <image>'
   }
}
```

Where:

- *CREDENTIALS_ID* stands for key in Jenkis under which you store credentials to your docker registry.
- *PRIVATE_REGISTRY_URL* stands for url of your private docker registry. If you are using docker hub then it should be empty.

Comment: That doesn't run the build and does not use the Docker Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend the declarative syntax for building a Docker image  bcos it seems that every important step requires falling back to the old scripting syntax. But if you must, a hybrid approach seems to work.

First a detail about the scm step: when I defined the Jenkins "Pipeline script from SCM" project that fetches my Jenkinsfile with a declarative pipline from git, Jenkins cloned the repo as the first step in the pipeline *even tho I did not define a scm step*.

For the build and push steps, I can only find solutions that are a hybrid of old-style scripted pipeline steps inside the new-style declarative syntax. For example see gustavoapolinario's work at Medium:

https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9

which has this hybrid pipeline definition:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    registry = "gustavoapolinario/docker-test"
    registryCredential = 'dockerhub'
    dockerImage = ''
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
      steps {
        git 'https://github.com/gustavoapolinario/microservices-node-example-todo-frontend.git'
      }
    }
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry( '', registryCredential ) {
            dockerImage.push()
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Remove Unused docker image') {
      steps{
        sh "docker rmi $registry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because the first step here is a clone, I think he built this example as a *standalone pipeline* project in Jenkins (not a Pipeline script from SCM project).